# Javascript/Jquery: code not repeating with any loop I've tried

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

Is there a reason why I am unable to loop the autoscroll function in the following code?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    autoScroll();
});

function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
}
```

I've already tried several answers to other simular questions on this site with no success.

**EDIT:**

To put it simply I have two html pages, index.html and iframe.html. Index.html has a iframe pointing to iframe.html. The above code is running on iframe.html. The above code scrolls down the webpage contained in the iframe. What I want it to do is go back to the top of the page after it finishes scrolling to the bottom and then repeat for 'X' amount of times.

I've already tried the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var i = 0;
  do
    autoScroll();
    i++
  while(i<10);

});

function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
  var i = 0;
  while(i<10){
    autoScroll();
    i++
  };

});

function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
  for(i<10; i<10; i++){
    autoScroll();
  };

});

function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
}

$(window).load(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    autoScroll();
  }, 3000)

});

function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

    $(window).scroll(function() {   
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
        }
    });
}
```

I've also tried **all** of the above shown above but around the contents of the autoScroll function like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    autoScroll();
});

function autoScroll()
    var i = 0;
    do
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear');

        $(window).scroll(function() {   
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
               $(window).scrollTop(0);
           }
        });
    i++
    while(i<10);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just explain what you want it to do, as that code doesn't make much sense on its own.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop the autoscroll"? What exactly is the problem? What other "similar questions" have you looked at? What have you tried already?

Comment: Add some code that you have tried?!

Comment: what do you want to do in actual. your question doesn't make sense

Comment: Edit the question, explain what you want to achieve, and try putting a runnable/complete code in jsfiddle or in code snippet tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function: by calling  autoScroll(); after the animation is completed:

```
autoScroll();
function autoScroll(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 22500,'linear',function(){
     $(window).scrollTop(0);
             autoScroll();
    });
}
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/bbdsj2bg/1/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still won't loop

Comment: by "loop" what do you mean?

Comment: sorry I meant repeat. As stated no above, I'm trying to use a loop function to repeat the code x amount of times

Comment: I put `autoScroll()` in a `$(window).load` function so it starts when the window loads but it still only runs the code once and then stops.

Comment: @Selida as you can see in my demo the scroll loops

Comment: I still can't get it to work when I apply it to my web page, however I can see it works in you demo

Comment: you may have other plugins that interfere with this code

Comment: Just a vanilla xampp setup